# only select children with children from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to get an output of only the nodes that have a child node of their own. There is a for-each going over the level1 nodes, for each an expression is checked and if that returns true, then we want to copy all level2 tags which have a level3 tag. The problem is that names of the "level2" tags are unknown. Only the "level3" node names are set (known) and is the same for all level3 nodes. The input would be the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <level1>
    <level2>data</level2>
    <level2>data</level2>
    <level2>
        data
        <level3>data</level3>
    </level2>
    <level2>data</level2>
    <level2>
        data
        <level3>data</level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
  <level1>
  ....
  </level1>
</root>
```

From which I would need the ouput to be:

```
<level2>
    data
    <level3>data</level3>
</level2>
<level2>
    data
    <level3>data</level3>
</level2>
```

I tried getting them by using:

```
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::level3" />
</xsl:copy>
```

but this will only return me the "level3" tags and data. Is it possible to also return that level3's parent without knowing the name of that node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this XPath expression to select these elements:**

```
/*/level1/*[level3]
```

This selects all children-elements of `level1` children of the top element, that (the children-elements of `level1`) have at least one `level3` child.

**This could be more general -- suppose you don't know any names and want to get all elements at depth 3 that still have children elements**. Then one XPath expression selecting these is:

```
/*/*/*[*]
```

**Or, if the wanted depth is not known statically (in advance) -- say it is given in a variable `$N`**, then:

```
//*[count(ancestor::*) = $N - 1] [*]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the context of `level1`, the instruction:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*[level3]"/>
```

will copy all child elements of the current `level1` element that have a child element named `level3`, along with all their descendant nodes.